# Convert output format of timezone with help of Python

Tags: python, datetime, format, timezone

Maybe someone came across and will be able to give advise.

I am getting the time zone "Europe / Moscow", but it needs to be converted to "UTC + 3".
Only an idea with a dictionary comes to mind, but this is rather a last resort.
I would not be surprised if there are ready-made solutions, but I did not google it well)

Example:

```
timezone = "Europe/Moscow" -> timezone = "UTC+3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Python 3.9+:

You can use the `zoneinfo` package. ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html))

Make sure to consider daylight saving time.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import zoneinfo
zone = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("Europe/Moscow")

offset = datetime.now(zone).utcoffset().total_seconds()//(60*60)
print(offset) # 3 / 4 - This depends on daylight saving time
print(f"UTC+{int(offset)}") # UTC+3 / UTC+4
```

### Older:

Try `pytz`, but make sure to consider daylight saving time. ([link](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/))

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

moscow_tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow")

offset = moscow_tz.utcoffset(datetime.now())

print(offset) # 3:00:00 / 4:00:00 - This depends on daylight saving time
print(f"UTC+{int(offset.total_seconds()//(60*60))}") # UTC+3 / UTC+4
```